# Excel chart changing all data labels from value to series name simultaneously

Tags: excel, charts, stacked, labeling

I am having this problem in excel stacked column chart while trying to change the labels. My graph has multiple columns and hundreds of stacked values (series) in each column.

By selecting chart then from layout->data labels->more data labels options ->label options ->label contains-> (select)series name, I can only get one series name replacing its respective label values. For more than hundred series stacked in columns i want them all to be changed at once, is there any way out? why it does not change them all at once?

Comment: seems there is no solution for this :(

Comment: Answered the duplicate - [VBA Change Data Labels on a Stacked Column chart from 'Value' to 'Series name'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838504/vba-change-data-labels-on-a-stacked-column-chart-from-value-to-series-name) - before getting linked to this one. I suppose some kind of merge is in order?

Comment: Though, its an old one... will your solution change all at once?

Comment: btw, mine is duplicate or the linked is duplicate? just wondering...

Comment: I'd say the new one is the duplicate, but the answer is the same for both and that's the one I answered, so... I'll leave it to whatever mods come round to decide :P @tod

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I wanted to post what I figured out.  I was having the same problem in the pivot table chart.  I was unable to change ALL of the labels at once.  What I did was remove the series from the chart all together.  I then was able to select the "series" data label and have it change all the labels.  After I did that I simply added the series back in and it populated all of my data labels with the "series" information.

Comment: @tod, flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

Comment: @scopchanov, the flag I have used says: **"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. "**