# VBA Change Data Labels on a Stacked Column chart from 'Value' to 'Series name'

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I would like to change the data labels on a stacked column chart from 'value' to 'series name'.

The chart I want to edit:
[image]

I have searched the best I could on the internet and the only way I think this can be done is by using VBA. I am still a VBA noob so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't unchecking "Value" and checking "Series Name" in the chart formatting dialog open at the left of your picture do exactly what you are asking about? http://i.imgur.com/Inpf80X.png

Comment: For some weird reason you can only select one label at a time So when you go to change it it only changes the one you selected. And there is no way to select and change them all like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going into Excel, I select the chart I want to edit and then select all labels by going to Chart Tools > Add Chart Element > Data Labels > More Data Label Options

[image]

Next I uncheck whatever options I don't want in my labels, and check those I do want, under the "Label Options" in the dialog I just opened.

[image]

This works fine for me, but if it doesn't for you, or  you for some other reason want to edit the labels via VBA, this script snippet sets the labels of a given chart to the series name:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Grafar, utvikling").ChartObjects("Graf3").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2)
    If Not .HasDataLabels Then
      .ApplyDataLabels
    End If
    If Not .DataLabels.ShowSeriesName Then
      .DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Clearly you need to switch the worksheetnames, chart-name, etc. to whatever you have in your chart - it shouldn't be  very hard to figure out, but if you have any trouble feel free to comment  on the question if you do have any problems.

I created the macro by using the macro recorder, and then editing the results,  it can often give a good starting point for whatever task you attempt to do. In my experience it can be easier to figure out the object names / structures in Excel-VBA this way, than trying to figure it out from scratch.

Considering the above doesn't do what you want, I suspect that each column in your chart is one series. To quickly display the `SeriesName` for each dataseries in the chart, try looping over all the series in the chart:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim se As Series

  For Each se In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Grafar, utvikling").ChartObjects("Graf3").Chart.SeriesCollection
    If Not se.HasDataLabels Then
      se.ApplyDataLabels
    End If
    If Not se.DataLabels.ShowSeriesName Then
      se.DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
    End If
    If se.DataLabels.ShowValue Then
      se.DataLabels.ShowValue = False
    End If
  Next se

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eirkdaude

Thanks for such a detailed response.

Here is a video showing what happened with your two solutions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcjX3dHSF6M It does a better job of explaining what happened then my text below

Comment: Using the first approach where I go to "Chart Tools > Add Chart Element > Data Labels > More Data Label Options" it initially adds all the data labels with "Value" and "Show Leader Lines" checked. When I go to change them there is no way to select all the data labels.  I can only select labels that have the same column in the data. So when I select them and change them from 'Value' to 'Series' it is only those ones that I was able to highlight that I can change. 

The VBA macro  had a similar result. It only changes the data labels for one of the columns of data.

Comment: @JonathanDeWet I suspect each of your columns may be one dataseries - see my update of the answer to see how you may solve this. If my answer's been of use to you, please upvote and / or mark it as a solution to your question.

Comment: Worked Great (almost). The only problem is that it shows 'Value' and 'Series name' together. I only want it to show 'Value'. ![Example](http://i.imgur.com/K5wJOA1.png) Thanks again!

Comment: In order to turn off values, you'd put something like `se.DataLabels.ShowValue = False` into the loop. I am sure you can figure out the last few kinks on your own :) For reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn300818.aspx @JonathanDeWet

Comment: I have been playing around and trying to get it to work. I recorded some macros and looked at some other VBA to see how to add another thing inside an 'if then' but I couldn't figure it out. This is my attempt http://i.imgur.com/dUcnC3d.png If you have any thoughts of how to fix it that would be cool.

Comment: @JonathanDeWet You don't need to put it inside the `If`-statement, but inside the loop. Updated answer. Strictly speaking I am not sure if the conditionals are even necessary, but I put them in there to be sure nothing wonky would happen if it tried to do something which had already been done....

Comment: I edited the second VBA thingy you made to work with the update you made to the first one. It works great. Thanks for sticking with me :)

Comment: Whoops put it in the wrong code block - gotta fix that! :-D

Comment: There is this other question asked a long time ago that can be fixed using the same solution you posted here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725557/excel-chart-changing-all-data-labels-from-value-to-series-name-simultaneously

If you don't want to answer it I am happy to (I will say its your solution) but I didn't want to steal your genius

Comment: @JonathanDeWet I'll flag it as a duplicate